# How to Align Checkbox next to text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a problem aligning my checkbox next to my text.

I am developing a simple to do list application. I have created the paragraph element using `JavaScript` and I created the checkbox using a `span` element.

The `listElement` `id` in my `CSS` derives from the `JavaScript`, where I set the paragraph element id to `listElement`

Here is what I am aiming for:

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

[image]

```js
var toDoItems = [];
var i = 1;
var userInput;
var listElement;
var checkBox;

document.getElementById("addItem").onclick = function() {
  userInput = prompt("Enter your Todo: ")
  toDoItems.push(userInput);
  stylePara();
  document.getElementById("item-list").
  append(listElement);
}

function stylePara() {
  listElement = document.createElement("p");
  listElement.id = "listElement";
  listElement.innerHTML = userInput;
}
```

```css
#listElement {
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<h1>My Tasks</h1>
<h4><span id="number1"></span> tasks</h4>
<button id="addItem">Add item</button>
<div id="item-list">
  <span><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh sorry I will edit the post

Comment: Even now the requirement is not clear. You meant to have the `Add item` button next to the check box?

Comment: @brk: I think is obvious (seeing the picture) that he wants the checkbox next to the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Play this snippet, I think you'll like it.

[image: preview of snippet]

I based on [this idea](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp):

- the real checkbox remains invisible
- there is another visible checkbox, stylized (the check is actually an rotated angle), that changes its style according to the state of the real checkbox

Also:

- You weren't creating the checkbox with javascript, only the label
- I changed your javascript: Now it forms the propper html and inject it with the [insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method
- I also added the cross-over effect when unchecked

```js
var toDoItems = [];
var i = 1;
var userInput;
var listElement;
var checkBox;

document.getElementById("addItem").onclick = function() {
  userInput = prompt("Enter your Todo: ")
  toDoItems.push(userInput);
  document.getElementById("item-list").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', stylePara());
}

function stylePara() {
  var html = '';
  
  html += '<label class="container">';
  html +=   '<input type="checkbox">';
  html +=   '<span class="checkmark"></span>';
  html +=   '<span class="checklabel">' + userInput + '</span>';
  html += '</label>';

  return html;
}
```

```css
/* The container */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 40%;
  /*this is the general left margin*/
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */

.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Create a custom checkbox */

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 0;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  background-color: #eee;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */

.container:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* When the checkbox is checked, add a green background */

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}


/* label when unchecked */

.checklabel {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}


/* label when checked */

.container input:checked~.checklabel {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}


/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}


/* Show the checkmark when checked */

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
  top: 10px;
  left: 15px
}


/* Style the checkmark/indicator */

.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>To do list</h1>
<button id="addItem">Add item</button>
<div id="item-list">
  <label class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    <span class="checklabel">Example item</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Sun, for the edit. But I restored the indents in creation of "html" variable in javascript. I made it that way simulating the html indentation. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Cheers, just what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
.input-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.icon {
  padding: 10px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  min-width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.input-field {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
}
```

Using CSS is much easier to align items on your page. Please see the W3Schools tutorial - it's simple and easily explained https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_form_icon.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can use checkbox hack for this

```css
.check {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  background-color: black;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .text {
  background-color: #0f0;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="a" />
<label class="check" for="a"></label><div class="text">Get shit done</div>
```

Comment: Yes, he needs javascript to add the items

Answer (score 0):

Start with this minimal markup and CSS, and then add your own styles.

```css
.item {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}

/* Sample custom styles. */
.item p {
    background: red;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <p>Item 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <p>Item 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

These will always be in alignment with each other irrespective of your custom styles.